# Python getch + print from separate thread

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I have a program that runs in the terminal and waits for a keystroke. I launch a background thread on initialization. I want to do a `print` from the background thread, but the output is indented. Why is the output indented? Is it possible to make it not be indented?

```
import sys, termios, tty, time, threading

def getch():
  # Taken from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/510357/python-read-a-single-character-from-the-user

  fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
  old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
  try:
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
  finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
  return ch


def do_stuff():
  for i in range(5):
    time.sleep(1)
    print 'test {}'.format(i)

t = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=[], kwargs={})
t.start()


print 'press any key'
print getch()
print 'done'
```

Output:

```
press any key
test 0
      test 1
            test 2
                  test 3
                        test 4
                              x
done
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird hack, but printing backspace characters seems to fix the problem:

```
import sys, termios, tty, time, threading, random

def getch():
  # Return a single character from stdin.

  fd = sys.stdin.fileno()
  old_settings = termios.tcgetattr(fd)
  try:
    tty.setraw(sys.stdin.fileno())
    ch = sys.stdin.read(1)
  finally:
    termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old_settings)
  return ch


def do_stuff():
  prev_line = ''
  for i in range(10):
    time.sleep(.5)
    next_line = str(i) * random.randrange(1, 10)
    print '\b' * len(prev_line) + next_line
    prev_line = next_line


t = threading.Thread(target=do_stuff, args=[], kwargs={})
t.start()

print 'press any key'
print getch()
print 'done'
```